# Returning SaMAccount of members of a group

Tags: ldap

Is it possible to return the SaMAccountAttribute of members along with the distinguished name when querying the members of a group?

I have the query `(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=group))`  but it just returns the distinguished names of each user.  I'm trying to avoid having to query each user just to get the needed attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope it is not possible natively. That is the way the LDAP protocol works.

There is no join between requests.

Another approach could be :

- Retrieve the DN of the group corresponding to the filter `(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=group))`
- Search for all the users with a filter like : `(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=<GROUP DN>))` and retrieve the `samAccountName` attribute only.

You will have the attribute you need, and every entry returned by a LDAP search should be accompanied by its DN.